# Replace array values with new defined values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
//Get message from textarea
var msg = $('#mytextarea').val();

//Convert string to array of letters
// eg. cata = ['c','a','t','a']
var msgLettersAsArray = msg.split('');
```

What I need to do now is replace the single letters,something like this

```
c = b;
a = e;
t = c;
a = e;

//array neeeds to be converted from this:
var array = ['c','a','t','a'];

// to this:
var array = ['b','e','c','e'];
```

Is there any way to achieve this?
All I need to do is replace the letters that are already in the array with letters of my choice

Comment: Could you just replace the letters bevor splitting the String? `msg.replace(/c/g, 'b')`

Comment: yes, but in the "real" code I need to replace all letters from a-z,0-9
using the replace method would require me to call the replace function for every single letter I need to change.Am I wrong?

Comment: it is possible with one call to `replace()`: `var map = {c: 'b', a: 'e', t: 'c'}`; `msg.replace(/[a-z0-9]/g, function (i) { return map[i] || i; })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just making an answer out of my comment:

Like OP said, its ok to be done without the `split()`. And its possible to do with only one call to `String.replace()`:

```
var map = {
  c: 'b',
  a: 'e',
  t: 'c'
};

msg.replace(/[a-z0-9]/g, function (i) { return map[i] || i; })
```

The RegExp can possibly made event simpler:

```
msg.replace(/./g, function (i) { return map[i] || i; })
```

Comment: That's what happens when the OP doesn't explain what he needs ;)

Comment: you are completely right, you deserve the best answer anyway

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple, just define a translation map and use `Array.prototype.map`.

```
var translationMap = {
    c: 'b',
    a: 'e',
    t: 'c'
};

//returns ['b','e','c','e']
['c','a','t','a'].map(function (letter) { return translationMap[letter] || letter; });
```

EDIT: It seems you actually just wanted to replace letters in the string, in this case @phylax answer would be correct. There is no need to use arrays for a simple string replacement.

Comment: Please consider the case that `letter` is not in the `translationMap` before I give you an upvote :-)

Comment: @Bergi OP has fixed replacemtn map

Answer (score 1):

```
function replaceChars(str, map) {
    var i, reg = "";
    for (i in map)
        reg += i;
    return str.replace(
        new RegExp("["+reg.replace(/(\]|-|\\)/,"\\$1")+"]",'g'),
        function(char) { return map[char]; }
    );
}
```

```
//Get message from textarea
var msg = $('#mytextarea').val(); // "cata"

replaceChars(msg, {c:'b', a:'e', t:'c', a:'e'}); // "bece"
```

Comment: Did he want a string or an array? I am confused. Anyway at worst it's just a question of playing with `split` and `join` ;)

Comment: @plalx: The `.map()` solution was too trivial and there was a `String.prototype.replaceChars` function in my personal helper lib so I just posted it :-)

Answer (score 0):

not tested but it should work

```
 var replaxe = {
     'c':'b',
     'e':'d'
    },
  array = ['c','e'],
  result = [];

  for(var item in array){
    result.push(replaxe[item]);
  }


  console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just use a `for` loop:

```
var array = ['c','a','t','a'];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    var cur = array[i];
    if (cur == 'c') {
        array[i] = 'b';
    } else if (cur == 'a') {
        array[i] = 't';
    } else if (cur == 't') {
        array[i] = 'c';
    }
}
```

But using an object to store these mappings can make your code even more compact:

```
var array = ['c','a','t','a'];
var transform = { 'c': 'b', 'a': 'e', 't': 'c' };
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    array[i] = transform[array[i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RUN THIS IN YOUR FIRE BUG CONSOLE

var array = ['c','a','t','a'];
var myarray = [];
for(i=0; i<=array.length; i++)
{
    if(array[i] == 'c' )
    {
        array[i] = 'b'
    }
    if(array[i] == 'a' )
    {
        array[i] = 'e'
    }
    if(array[i] == 't' )
    { 
        array[i] = 'c'
    }
    if(array[i] == 'a' )
    {
        array[i] = 'a'
    }
}
```

console.log(myarray);

Comment: Please use a [reasonable indentation](http://jsbeautifier.org/), put your text out of the code, and don't shout (caps).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a switch-case for every element in the array.

```
for (i in array) {
    switch (array[i]) {
    case "c":
        array[i] = "b";
        break;
    case "a":
        array[i] = "e";
        break;
    case "t":
        array[i] = "c";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `replace`? Seriously? Also [don't use `for in` on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)

Comment: @Bergi That was really stupid of me. Just a bit tired after a busy day.